# xpages adding @formula in list

Tags: xpages

There is a client notes application and in its main form, there is a dialogList having this formula: ( C21331:312321C is, actually, the replica ID, in this example it's just a random number )

```
_view := "vw1";
_vieww :="vw1";



x :=@Sort(@Unique ( @DbColumn( "" : "NoCache" ; C21331:312321C; _view; 1 ) );[Ascending]);
y :=@Unique ( @DbColumn( "" : "NoCache" ; @DbName ; _vieww ; 1));

y:x
```

How to use thee above code in my combobox computed values?  I tried:

```
    var _view = "vw1";
    var _vieww= "vw2"; 

    db = new Array(@Sort(@Unique ( @DbColumn( "" : "NoCache" , C21331:312321C, _view, 1 ) );[Ascending]);

    db1 = new Array(@Unique ( @DbColumn( "" : "NoCache" ; @DbName ; _vieww ; 1)));

   db:db1
```

How can I achieve this functionalty in xpages? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.sort()` to sort an array (@Sort is not implemented in SSJS) and `.concat()` to concatenate two arrays or an array and a string:

```js
var a = [].concat(@Unique(@DbColumn( ... ))).sort();
var b = @Unique(@DbColumn( ... ));
return a.concat(b);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. By the time, I already resolved it with: @List(@DbColumn(...),@DbColumn(...)), but your suggestion is more elegant.

Comment: Strangely, now I have an error: [TypeError] Error calling method 'sort()' on an object of type 'String [JavaScript Object]' - at var a = @Unique(@DbColumn(dbname, "vwNumeCompanii", 0)).sort(); // where var dbname = session.getServerName() + "!!" + "XPAgenda.nsf";

Comment: OK, seems your @DbColumn() returns only one value as a string. So, you have to make sure you have an array before you call sort(). I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: MFG - you might want to go to openNTF and check out this snippet.  http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=dblookup-dbcolumn-with-cache-sort-and-unique

It's a better @DbColumn/@DbLookup and includes a sorting parameter as well as unique.

Comment: @KnutHerrmann this combobox values might be the problem of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863015/xpages-error-when-trying-to-access-edit-mode-in-client-notes . Could you look at this question, please? Thank you in advance.