# xpages error when trying to access edit mode in client notes

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying to open some doc. from a viewPanel inside the client notes. The application also runs on web.

When I open the doc. in read mode, and then click the Edit button:

```
<xp:button value=" Editare" id="buttonEdit"
            rendered="#{javascript:!currentDocument.isEditable()}" >

        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:changeDocumentMode mode="edit" var="Contr"></xp:changeDocumentMode>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

I get the following error:

Exception

java.lang.String incompatible with javax.faces.model.SelectItem

this it happens only in notes client.

From the stack trace:

```
 com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getOptionNumber(Unknown Source)
 com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(Unknown Source)
 com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(Unknown Source)
 com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(Unknown Source)
 .... ....
```

After deleting one by one combos, I noticed that the error is at this one, which values are:

```
var a = [].concat(@Unique(@DbColumn(dbname, "vwA", 0))).sort();
var b = @Unique(@DbColumn(@DbName(),"vwB",0));
return a.concat(b);
```

Any ideas why/ and how can I fixed this issue?

Comment: The Exception refers to a SelectItem which you usually find nested inside a combobox or the likes. Please post that portion of your page; the part you posted is absolutely straightforward; I think this kind of code is very common in Xpages, both in the browser and in XPinC apps

Comment: @LotharMueller I'm using numerous comboBox elements. Could I find exactly at what comboBox the problem persists?

Comment: if it's not in the verbose runtime error message it probably is somewhere in the stack trace; try to work your way through it from the buttom up. Most probably you'll find a familiar element somewhere like the combo's ID or something

Comment: So, copy the XPage. Remove one combobox at a time until it stops throwing the error. That's the one to fix.

Comment: @LotharMueller I don't see any familiar element, such as comboBox ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very likely that the error comes from your SSJS variable `dbname`. Please double check which value is set to this variable.

I get the same error `java.lang.String incompatible with javax.faces.model.SelectItem` if `dbname` is a **string** instead of an **array**.

Comment: I found it now: session.getServerName returns nothing in the Notes client.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, stack traces don't help me much when isolating an error. However, I can guess that your problem is that the value of a selectItems (plural) is set to a string rather than something with multiple values. A selectItem (singular) can have a string as it's value, but not a selectItems (plural).

So, this set of selectItems for a combobox is valid:

```
<xp:selectItems>
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:applicationScope.globalSettings.allCurrencies}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:selectItems>
```

As is this one:

```
<xp:comboBox id="emailTypeCB1" value="#{newOrgDoc.EMailType}">
    <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:var keywordChoices = new TS_Keywords();
var tmp = keywordChoices.Lookup("Contact / email types", true);
return keywordChoices.getDefaultValue();}]]></xp:this.defaultValue>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="-- choose --" id="selectItem14">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItems id="selectItems12">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return new TS_Keywords().Lookup("Contact / email types", true);}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
</xp:comboBox>
```

But, if I tried this, it wouldn't work if the viewScope.myChoices was a string and not something with multiple values:

```
<xp:comboBox id="emailTypeCB1" value="#{newOrgDoc.EMailType}">
    <xp:selectItems id="selectItems12">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.myChoices;}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
</xp:comboBox>
```

I would assume that the difference is not just that you opened one in XPiNC and one in the browser, but that the value was set differently in each - ending up as a string when you were in Notes.

Comment: thanks for your tips. I updated my question / I think I found the combobox which causes this issue.

Comment: session.getServerName returns nothing in the Notes client. Correct it with a simple string, and now it works. I appreciate your help, @DavidNavarre.